# ASP.NET - MVC 5 SQL Server Database Navigation

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, navigation

Could somebody please explain how to insert data from a SQL Server database into an existing ASP.NET MVC 5 project?

I have a file `Shared/_layout.vbhtml` which has the following lines:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
```

However I would like to replace this with the actual data from the Navigation table. I have added a new Data Connection to SQL Server within the ASP.NET MVC 5 project, but I am now unsure as how to bind the connection this page.

Any examples or advice would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: I dont think there is an answer to this question. YOu should go over tutorials and understand how things work.

Comment: I am  very new to this, I am trying to port a Classic ASP project, Visual Studio 2013 and MVC 5 is taking some getting used to the new structure. I can see how that Views (.vbhtml) can reference Controllers, so is data bound to the controller and not the View and if so are you aware of any tutorials as I am struggling to find any?

Comment: Here's a good starting point from Microsoft: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store

Comment: Thank you so much, the example is in Visual C# where as I'm using Visual Basic but I get the idea, a massive load off, again thank you :-)

Answer (score 6):

Below is the way to solve out your problem.

**Your controller code**

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            // Simply fetch from the database and set the action name and controller name with your own logic like using of loop or any.

            // Also, You have to set style and css what you want exactly as per your theme.

            sb.AppendFormat("First Link", Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName"));
            sb.AppendFormat("Second Link", Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName"));
            sb.AppendFormat("Third Link", Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName"));

            // Set ViewBag property with string builder object
            ViewBag.DynamicActions = sb.ToString();

            return View();

        }
```

**Place the below code in _layout view file.**

```
<div>
    @if (ViewBag.DynamicActions != null)
    {
      @Html.Raw(ViewBag.DynamicActions)
    }
</div>
```